# copying a list of words from excel to some asp.net text control

Tags: asp.net, excel

Say you had an Excel file containing a column filled with words,
and you'd like to allow the user to copy the cells from that excel
and paste them inside something like a textbox (we're talking ASP.NET 3.5). 
What would you do?

(Any other control would be fine, I just need something the code-behind can later on
read from into a db.)

HELP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy a set of cells, and paste it into a plain text target (e.g. a textbox), it'll be inserted as a multiline text with tab-separated text values. In the example below I just pasted a set of 5 cells from Excel. And you're going to have no problem reading this data from the TextBox.Text property for processing. Bear in mind that since potentially you copy/paste cells from several rows, you should setup TextMode="multiline" in your TextBox.

Pasted cells:

```
A1  B1
A2  B2
A3
```